# Debian unable to locate package primus-nvidia

Tags: debian, apt, nvidia, bumblebee

I am attempting to install three packages through the following command:

`apt install bumblebee-nvidia primus-nvidia nvidia-smi`

The bumblebee-nvidia and nvidia-smi work individually however, primus-nvidia can't be found. I think I might be missing a line in my sources.list. Here is my current sources.list:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main non-free contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

What do I need to do to install primus-nvidia? Any help is appreciated.
For reference, I installed debian through a non-free iso

Answer (score 1):

The *primus-nvidia* package was probably not deemed ready for *stable* inclusion when Debian 10 was released. Anyway, today it's [present](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=primus-nvidia&searchon=names&suite=all) in *unstable* (*sid*), *testing* (*bullseye*), and, interesting for you, *stable-backports* ([*buster-backports*](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/primus-nvidia)).

So you have to first add buster-backports in your repository, following this guide https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/ (still including all three *main*, *contrib*, *non-free* sections rather than only *main*) and update packages.

Then you can install it using:

```
apt-get -t buster-backports install primus-nvidia
```

Please note that *buster-backports* packages can depend on other packages in *buster-backports*. This could trigger an upgrade of other components, like nvidia drivers.

Note also that the version shows that upstream dates back to 2015, but that's indeed the latest [upstream release](https://github.com/amonakov/primus/releases) as of today.